# Evaluate $F'(X)$ for the function $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{u}\sin u \ du$

Tags: calculus

I had to do an exercise for my calculus class that said the following:

> Evaluate $F'(x)$ and $F''(x)$ for the function $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{u}\sin u \ du$.

And my answer was:
[image]

As you can see, my teacher told me that I need to use FTC, that is, the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. But I don't really understand what he really means. Any idea?

Thank you very much.

Comment: what does the fundamental theorem of calculus tell you?

Comment: Do you understand what the FTOC means?

Comment: Recall FTC statement https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements
Are the hypotheses satisfied?

Comment: It tells us f is continuous on the closed interval [a,b] and F is the indefinite integral then we can use the Barrow's law.

Comment: I believe your solution is right but was not explained correctly, i.e. you did not "show your workings" - up to the standard the teacher requested. He/she probably expected that you would explicitly invoke FTC and explain why it can be applied. Going into such detail may seem unnecessary to you, but making careful steps makes you also aware not to use FTC when it does not apply.

Comment: @user8734617 Yes, but the problem is that don't really understand how the FTC is related to this.

Comment: You just need to prepend your solution with the phrase "Since the integrand is continuous using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus we get". The fact that $F'(x) =\sqrt{x} \sin x$ is not automatic but via FTC. Otherwise how did you evaluate $F'(x) $?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $I$ is an intervall, $a \in I$ and  $f:I \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, then the FTC says

$(\int_a^x f(u) du)'=f(x)$